# Firebase JS SDK version change

Tags: firebase

I am currently fetching the JS SDK from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.4.0/firebase.js". I want to make sure that my setup that doesn't change. Can I assume that Firebase would not change this file (or any version for that matter) without changing the filename?

Answer (score 1):

Never assume that internal files won't change without changing the file name. There is a good chance that methods inside that file may indeed get changed to match with current changes or upgrades in technologies. Usually, though, major developers will do their best to insure the changes will not break anything in legacy files.

Answer (score 0):

Firebase practices semantic versioning. This means that minor versions are backwards compatible, while major versions may contain breaking changes.

So version 5.4 should be drop in compatible with all 5.x versions.

But if you upgrade from a 4.x or lower version, you may have to make changes.

Whether this is actually needed depends on what products you use, and the changes to those products between the versions. The older the SDK you're upgrading from, and the larger the number of products you use, the higher the chance that you'll need to upgrade.

If you want to check what has changed, check the detailed release notes here: https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/js

Comment: This doesn't answer my question exactly. Once a JS file of a specific version is published by Firebase, would Firebase change that specific file in the future?

Comment: Ah... got it. In that case the answer is much simpler: a version once published will not be changed.

Comment: Thanks! If you can post it as part of your answer, I will accept it.